# Record audio only with Videojs-record without wavesurfer

Tags: javascript, video.js, wavesurfer.js, videojs-record

I'm using Videojs and Videojs-record in my Rails app to create messages and capture video and screen from the users browser.
I'm building a custom UI using tailwindcss and I'm using Stimulusjs to handle all the button clicks etc.

Instead of using the controls within the Videojs player to get the devices, I have a button that calls an action in my stimulus controller.

```
startCapture() {
  let options = {
    // video.js options
    controls: false,
    bigPlayButton: true,
    loop: false,
    fluid: true,
    plugins: {
      // videojs-record plugin options
      record: {
        audio: true,
        video: {
          width: { min: 640, ideal: 852, max: 1280 },
          height: { min: 480, ideal: 480, max: 720 }
        }                    
      }
    }
  }
  player = videojs(this.previewMediaTarget, options, () => {
    console.log("Videojs-record is ready")
  }
}
```

This works great when I want to record video and screen/audio (with some alterations in the options), but I also want to give my users the ability to create audio messages.

When I change the options for my player to

```
audio: true,
video: false
```

Videojs-record automatically tries to use the wavesurfer library with the videojs-wavesurfer and microphone plugins.

The wavesurfer library is great and I wouldn't be opposed to using it, however the `player.record().getDevice()` Videojs-record method doesn't work when using it and instead it seems forces me to click the big button to enable the mic.
[image: big "enable mic" button in Videojs-record player]

I've tried finding a  similar method to `player.record().getDevice()` to enable the users microphone from within the wavesurfer.js and microphone plug in, but I haven't had any luck.

Is there a way for me to just `player.record().getDevice()` and only get the users mic without having to use the wavesurfer plugin? Or is there a videojs-wavesurfer method I haven't found that will enable me to use a custom button to `getDevice`?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

First, There is no way to not use wavesurfer with Videojs-record audio only, but I figured out how to use it in my project.

The problem I was running into was that I was trying to set the player options and build the player on activation of my Stimulus action, so after the controller was loaded. This was causing WaveSurfer.microphone.create() to not initialize.
I solved the issue by moving the options to the stimulus `connect()` action so the player is built when the Stimulus controller loads. Then in my action, I call `player.record().getDevice()` and all works perfectly.